# mongoengine can not load data correctly in concurrency

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

in a web service (flask web server, deployed with gunicorn, gevent workers) , there is a request handler will query a set of objects and update the status like below:

```
def update_status(job_id,info_ids):
    infos = Info.objects(job_id=job_id, info_id__in = info_ids)
    if len(infos) == 0:
       logger.error('infos are not found')
    for i in infos:
        pass
```

I'm sure the infos are in the database, other service will request to this in concurrency, but in some request , I logged the error in logs(infos are not found). I'm quite confused why the data can not be loaded sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other parts of your code, but I guess the Info class is your mongoengine document like this:

```
class Info(mongoengine.Document):
    job_id = mongoengine.StringField(...)
    info_id = mongoengine.StringField(...)
```

If it's true, you must use **Info.objects** instead of **Info.object** to access queryset of your collection (note the 's' at the end of objects). So, your code must be something like this:

```
infos = Info.objects(job_id=job_id, info_id__in = info_ids)
```

Comment: sorry to confused you, that is typo, actually in my code is 'objects'